# How to Make Div the Same Size as the Screen with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a sort of on-screen console emulator on a website. Basically I need a black div to stretch to the bottom of the screen. I also want to have stuff further down below the console. How do I do so? I've found a few answers but none of them work, maybe because I'm using Bootstrap 4 and most of the answers are for v3.

My HTML:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100hv;
}

#console {
  height: 100hv;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="console" class="row bg-dark text-white mh-100">
  <div class="col">
    Rohan Khajuria
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miswritten the class `h-100` (you wrote mh-100).

to inherit then height, you should have used percentage not viewport unit  :

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

or only used

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

demo:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#console {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="console" class="row bg-dark text-white h-100 m-0">
  <div class="col">
    Rohan Khajuria
  </div>
</div>
<p>Next</p>
```

---

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#console {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="console" class="row bg-dark text-white h-100 m-0">
  <div class="col">
    Rohan Khajuria
  </div>
</div>
<p>Next</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work but you used the wrong unit for your css height property. It's not hv its vh which is short for view height.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    #console, body {
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
<div id="console" class="row bg-dark text-white mh-100">
<div class="col">
    Rohan Khajuria
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the #console CSS, instead of height: 100hv; change hv to vh.

From

```
#console {
  height: 100hv;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

To

```
#console {
  height: 100vh;
  font-style: italic;
}
```